# How to type check a Date object in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function that takes a Date object as its paramater. I am not able to figure out how to annotate this.

```js
function diffDate (start: any, end:any) {
//....
}
```

How do I type annotate `start` and `end` as Date objects?

Comment: Does `: Date` not work?

Comment: stupid of me! it should.

Comment: It should because Flow comes with built-in definitions for Date class: https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js#L364

Comment: yes it did. thanks.

Comment: @aakash : Ramro rahecha question. Can u elaborate more on it :p

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks loganfsmyth and Nikita for the comments. It works as expected.

```js
function diffDate (start: Date, end: Date) {
   // ...
}
```